# Why just the two first Binding data are displayin?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, web, xamarin.forms

I know this must be easy, but i can not find the soluction.
Only the to 2 first data bind are displayed
{Binding Monto,StringFormat='{0:C}'  },{Binding FechaRegistro,StringFormat='{0:dd/MM/yy}' }

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" Refreshing="myListView_Refreshing" SeparatorColor="Orange" ItemTapped="myListView_ItemTapped" ItemSelected="myListView_ItemSelected">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
               <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
                     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                     <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                         <Image Source="https://aka.ms/campus.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill" />                                          
                     </StackLayout>
                     <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Spacing="1">
                              <Label Text="{Binding Monto,StringFormat='{0:C}'  }" FontSize="Small" TextColor="Blue" />
                             <Label Text="{Binding FechaRegistro,StringFormat='{0:dd/MM/yy}' }" FontSize="Small" TextColor="Black" />
                             <Label Text="{Binding FechaGasto,StringFormat='{0:dd/MM/yy}' }" FontSize="Small" TextColor="Black" />
                             <Label Text="{Binding TipoGasto}" FontSize="Small" TextColor="Black" />
                             <Label Text="{Binding TipoTransaccion}" FontSize="Small" TextColor="Black" />
                          </StackLayout>
                   </Grid>
</ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
```

Comment: Are you sure the row is tall enough to fit all of the data?

Comment: What does your ViewModel look like?

Comment: ItemTemplate Grid Row `*` won’t understand it needs to grow height. Try Row Height `Auto`, and set `HasUnevenRows=True`. If that doesn’t work, you may have to use a number for the row height.

Comment: You can put the last two line label at first to check if the problem is data binding or the view's height.